# Conditional Formatting by first couple of letters in string [VBA]

Tags: excel, vba, format, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make the font of some VBA cells bold by applying  `.FormatConditions.Add(xlTextString, etc.)` to a range.

I'd like to bold cells within this range if the value of the cells within the range start with the letter "V"

Below is a portion of the code I'm using. I'm interested in getting from here to a functional result, but I'm not sure where to go from here -- can anyone advise?

```
With .Range("L2:EZ5000").FormatConditions
    .Add(xlTextString,)


End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the macro recorder:

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
Formula1:="=LEFT(A1,1)=""V"""
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Bold = True
    .Italic = False
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

and tidied up:

```
Dim rng As Range, fc As FormatCondition

Set rng = Selection

rng.FormatConditions.Delete
With rng.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
         Formula1:="=LEFT(" & rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False) & ",1)=""V""")
    .SetFirstPriority
    .Font.Bold = True
    .StopIfTrue = False
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formatting is limited to three different formats. With VBA you can overcome this limitation. 
Using a loop and either `InStr` or `Left` to check the first character in each cell, and bold the font in the cells that have an "A" in the first character position.

```
For Each Cel in ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L2:EZ5000")
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "A") Then cel.Font.Bold = True

    'Or use... If (Left(cel, 1) = "A") Then cel.Font.Bold = True
Next cel
```